# EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19

Tags: boot

Specifications:

- Gigabyte X99P-SLI
- BIOS v F23
- BIOS Date 07/22/2016
- BIOS ID 8A07AG0H
- GeForce RTX3090 GPU

Ubuntu upgrade from desktop GUI: 18.04 -> 20.04;

```
journalctl -p err | grep EDAC reports following bootup error messages ...

~ kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
~ kernel: EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
~ kernel: EDAC sbridge: CPU SrcID #0, Ha #0, Channel #0 has DIMMs, but ECC is disabled
```

Symptom is benign; however, unable to resolve cause of problem.

Comment: You can ignore it but you should update UEFI anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i have the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I could’ve find a solution but as a temporary work around you can do the following:
1- in GRUB boot screen choose „Advanced options for Ubuntu“
2- choose an earlier kernel version to boot from (not recovery mode)
That worked for me as i can‘t boot to Ubuntu GUI otherwise, and i do it every time i want to use Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to the latest version and had the same problem. It seems it comes from my Nvidia card and their drivers. So I went to the "Advanced options for Ubuntu", chose the just new version (with recovery), and then: 1) selected to do a "clean" (which uninstalled the old Nvidia drivers and then updated them), and 2) selected "dpkg" to fix any corrupted packages (that it found out to be the same old drivers). Once 1) and 2) finished, I just verified everything by re-doing 1) and 2) again (this time nothing new was found and everything was up to date). I finished by rebooting and now my Ubuntu is working fine ;-)